# Homebrew formula advice

Tags: makefile, homebrew

I am trying to create a home-brew formula for [tableutil](http://expiretable.fnord.se).  I have come up with the following:

```
require "formula"

class Tableutil < Formula
  homepage "http://expiretable.fnord.se"
  url "https://github.com/gsson/tableutil/archive/master.tar.gz"
  sha1 "58ccb6826f28bf4e97b320317741a3971516279a"
  version "0.6"

  def install

    system "make", "PREFIX=#{prefix}"

    system "install"
  end

end
```

however I get the following error:

```
brew install tableutil 
==> Downloading https://github.com/gsson/tableutil/archive/master.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/tableutil-0.6.tar.gz
==> make PREFIX=/usr/local/Cellar/tableutil/0.6
==> install
usage: install [-bCcpSsv] [-B suffix] [-f flags] [-g group] [-m mode]
               [-o owner] file1 file2
       install [-bCcpSsv] [-B suffix] [-f flags] [-g group] [-m mode]
               [-o owner] file1 ... fileN directory
       install -d [-v] [-g group] [-m mode] [-o owner] directory ...
```

This is because the makefile for taleutil has the following

```
PREFIX?=/usr/local
INSTALL_BIN?=${PREFIX}/bin
INSTALL_MAN?=${PREFIX}/man/man1

INSTALL=/usr/bin/install

install: ${TARGET}
        ${INSTALL} -g bin -o root -m 755 ${TARGET} ${INSTALL_BIN}
        ${INSTALL} -g bin -o root -m 644 ${MAN} ${INSTALL_MAN}
```

I use system "make", "PREFIX=#{prefix}" to fix the Makefile so that it installs in the appropriate cellar, however I believe this is causing issues with the install component of the makefile, but I'm not sure what the issue is.

Answer (score 0):

On this line:

```
system "install"
```

You're invoking the program `install`, which *is* a binary (in `/usr/bin`) but you didn't pass it the right arguments.

However, you don't actually want to do that -- you want to invoke `make install`, so you should change that line to

```
system "make", "install"
```

Comment: Thanks, but if I make that change I still get the same error.  My understanding is that changing the prefix to be the cellar somehow makes the invocation of install incorrect, but I don't understand why or how this is the case